# How to insert value for a identity column in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've created two columns in sql table that one is a identity column and another one is a varchar column. I need to generate identity column starting from the value 1000. I had tried the below code snippet, but it was given error "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.."

```
   Place objPlace = new Place();
   objPlace.PNAME = "place 3";
   //objPlace.PID = 1003;   //purposefully commented for auto increment

   objContext.Places.AddObject(objPlace);
   objContext.SaveChanges();
```

I guess this is very basic question as I'm new to EF so please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign value to the Identity column. its meaningless.

if you want to change the starting value of your identity column, why not do it through a simple script?

```
context.Database
       .ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Place ALTER COLUMN Id IDENTITY (1000,1)");
```

this will insert `Place.Id` as 1000, for the first row in the table, and then 1001,1002... and so on for subsequent rows.

Comment: I couldn't find out anything called Database in datacontext.

Comment: Let me know how to set the identity column and use it in Entity framework

Comment: if you are using Entity-Framework 4.0 use this `context.ExecuteStoreQuery`

Comment: you can set a column Identity using fluent api like this `Property(s => s.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`.

Comment: it's pretty much helpful. Is it possible to set through EF Model Designer ?

Comment: in your OnModelCreating method in Context, you can add this line, `modelBuilder.Entity<Place>().Property(s=>s.Id).HasDat..`

Comment: I couldn't find any method called OnModelCreating method in my model. Please give me some advise.

Comment: it is available in the class you are inheriting DbContext, it is available. you have to override it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just wanting to do this in **EF** to learn the syntax? the reason I ask, is because you could set the seed on the column in **SSMS** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Let sql server generate identity. Set values for identity seed and Identity increment.

When column is identity , inserting record from entity framework will raise following error.
**Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MY_ENTITY' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**
To avoid error set entity property **StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"**

```
  <EntityType Name="MY_ENTITY">
              <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="UserID" />
              </Key>
              <Property Name="RecordID" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ExecuteSqlCommand()** command mentioned in above post will not work as mentioned in the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abd69be5-1410-4fdf-9e10-b9cf54bceea9/ef-codefirst-auto-increment-starting-value?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Aother solution is mentioned the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967881/entity-framework-auto-increment-with-starting-value)