# Entity Framework auto increment with starting value

Tags: entity-framework, auto-increment, entity-framework-6

I have a entity as follows

```
[Table("ESS_POS_SE_VERSION")]
public class Version
{
    [Key, Column("DETAIL_ID"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("DETAIL_TITILE")]
    public string DetailKey { get; set; }

    [Column("DETAIL")]
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

SO Id column is auto increment column, but I need to set its starting value to 1000. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider creating a custom database initializer.
It will be called each time your database is created or recreated.

For example:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void Seed(TContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('MyTable', RESEED, 1000);");
    }
}
```

Then register it:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set through Property or Attribute. However, you can run the command on this event:

Probably you can set through Alter: ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [IdentityColumn] IDENTITY (1000,1).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [IdentityColumn] IDENTITY (1000,1)) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Version ALTER COLUMN DETAIL_ID IDENTITY (1000,1)");
```