# EntityFramework Autonumeric value (not primary key)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My customer has requested that a field ("Code") in the database should be read-only incremental value starting from 100000. The funny thing is that the entity already has a primary key.

I don't know how to implement this easily with Entity Framework. What can I try?

Comment: You can try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967881/entity-framework-auto-increment-with-starting-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967881/entity-framework-auto-increment-with-starting-value)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the DatabaseGenerated Annotation?

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Code { get; set; )
```

This forces the database to generate the value and by using Identity it only generates the value on insert (not on update)

As far as I understand using this method would require you to set the value creation inside your database instance and [EF would not generate it for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add).

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question 100% but hopefully it sets you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Only one identity column can be created per table. It is not possible to have more than one identity column.

One solution would be to use SQL Server Sequence which was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Code_Seq START WITH 100000;

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Code_Seq;
```